# Ruby: Section an ansible hosts file into nested array

Tags: ruby, parsing

I'm retrieving an ansible hosts file via http.get which looks like this:

```
[group1]
host1
host2

[group2]
host3
host4
```

How do I iterate beginning at each group, and collapse the following lines until the next group into a nested hash like this?

```
{ "group1" => ["host1", "1host2"], "group2" => ["host3", "host4"] }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Direct INI Parse

If you don't want to do a full parse, you can treat your corpus as an INI file with sections. Such files can be tricky and have numerous edge cases, especially if you can't rigorously define how sections are separated. However, the following will work with your specific corpus.

```
# Read the file.
ini = File.read '/tmp/example.ini'

# Split the file into sections. Assumes only one blank line between
# sections.
sections = ini.scan /^\[.*?(?:\n\n|\z)/m

# Return an array of hashes, then merge them. Use the first element
# from each split as the hash key.
hash = sections.map do |section| 
  array = section.split
  key   = array.shift.delete '[]'
  { key => array }
end.reduce({}, :merge)

#=> {"group1"=>["host1", "host2"], "group2"=>["host3", "host4"]}
```

There are all kinds of ways this can fail on a more complex INI-like file, so you may need to do a more comprehensive parse of your file if you go this route. Alternatively, you can just save the result as a file, and then [parse the inventory into a Ruby hash using the Ansible CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43508214/1301972).

Comment: This worked perfectly. The key bit that I was missing was the /^\[.*?(?:\n\n|\z)/m regex. Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 2):

### Parse Inventory into Ruby Hash from Ansible's CLI Output

You can parse the output of an [Ansible inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html) as (mostly) JSON. This is actually easier and more reliable than parsing an INI-like file directly, although the Ansible CLI wraps the results you want inside a top-level `groups` value.

```
require 'json'

output = %x(ansible localhost -i /tmp/example.ini -m debug -a 'var=groups')
json   = JSON.parse(output.sub /^.*=>/, '')

json['groups']
#=> {"all"=>["host1", "host2", "host3", "host4"], "group1"=>["host1", "host2"], "group2"=>["host3", "host4"], "ungrouped"=>["localhost"]}

json['groups']['group1']
#=> ["host1", "host2"]

# Use Hash#dig on recent Rubies to simplify lookups.
json.dig 'groups', 'group2'
#=> ["host3", "host4"]
```

If you *really* need just the groups that start with the string `group`, you can extract them dynamically. For example:

```
json['groups'].keys.select { |k| k.start_with? 'group' }.map do |key|
  { key => json['groups'][key] }
end.reduce({}, :merge)
#=> {"group1"=>["host1", "host2"], "group2"=>["host3", "host4"]}
```

Comment: I should have been more obvious in that I don't have direct access to the machine with ansible - only access to the github. Otherwise this would have been very clear and easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [`ansible-inventory`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/ansible-inventory.html) command. An example for

```sh
ansible-inventory  -i path/to/inventory --export --list
```

An example result is like

```
{
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "db",
            "ungrouped",
            "web"
        ]
    },
    "db": {
        "hosts": [
            "demo_db"
        ]
    },
    "web": {
        "hosts": [
            "demo_app"
        ]
    }
}
```